# Rest API integration using Apache camel

Tags: apache-camel

I am new to Apache Camel, I have requirement to integrate two systems using REST API using Apache camel. I will receive a JSON message on my apache camel rest api endpoint(from source system).This json will contain arrays, I have to extract each array content and post to another **external api end point (target)**. So initially I tried to send incoming message to camel rest api as it is to the **target external api endpoint**. When I try that, then on application startup I get error. 
 I searched for similar exception but couldn't find anything concrete as in most of the example, source of message was used as a timer component.
Can't we make a call to **external** rest api end point?

Camel version : 3.4.0
Spring boot : 2.3.1

My router builder code

```
restConfiguration()
 .component("servlet").port(9090).host("localhost")
 .dataFormatProperty("prettyPrint", "true");

rest().post("/incoming")
      .consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
      .produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
      .route()
      .to("https://webhook.site/ff4a6f68-3b20-4bb2-afa1-c15ccae515ef");
```

Exception I am getting for target external endpoint

```
org.apache.camel.NoSuchEndpointException: 
No endpoint could be found for: 
https://webhook.site/ff4a6f68-3b20-4bb2-afa1-c15ccae515ef, 
please check your classpath contains the needed Camel component jar.
```

Please let me know, where I am making mistake.

Thanks in advance.

Ani

Answer (score 3):

**You don't have camel-http as dependency so add the dependency with correct version**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-http</artifactId>
    <version>x.x.x</version>
    <!-- use the same version as your Camel core version -->
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using camel 3.x you might also want to consider using dynamic endpoint component, in case your destination URL is defined dynamically. For example:

```
from("direct:login")
  .toD("http:myloginserver:8080/login?userid=${header.userName}");
```

Comment: Dynamic to is required only if your endpoint is computed at runtime. It is not required if the options are.